# AWS Glue View like Hive View

Tags: aws-glue-data-catalog

In Hive we all know we can define a non-materialized View. Easy.

My question is that if a similar construct can be created in AWS Glue Catalog? I see materialized view, but that it not what I mean.

I think it is not possible, but I may be missing something. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Athena for this. Athena is a serverless SQL Query engine (Presto) that can query your Data Catalog.

Athena provides a [view feature](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/views.html), where you can create non materialized views from your Glue Meta Data Catalog tables.

Comment: I saw that, so it means Glue itself does not have a view construct. Does that  not mean that it is better on EMR to use Hive Meta Store as opposed to Glue Catalog? My understanding is that Hive Metastore is better than Glue Data Catalogue/ Correct?

Comment: The Glue Data Catalog is basically a Hive Meta Store. The advantage of the Glue Data Catalog is that it integrates with a lot of different AWS services, which the Hive Meta Store does not. Hive provides more functionality in return.

Comment: That's a nice way of saying more of this but less of that. OK, we cannot have a view on a table in S3 in AWS.

Comment: So, just thinking about this answer and to be absolutely clear, if I may, if Hive uses the Glue Catalog, it cannot store the view definition in Glue?

Comment: in the Glue Catalog I mean.